# using onload function while rendering an image in typescript

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript

I am trying to render some image from a URL. However while I am doing this, it always takes some time for the image to be rendered. For this reason, I want to use a spinner. I couldn't find how to use onload function for this aim. I want to set loadingImg to true first then start rendering image and then in the end I want to set loadingImg false again, to make spinner disappear. But somehow I couldn't manage it.

```
<span class="spinner" *ngIf="loadingImg">
     Loading...
</span>
<img *ngIf="!loadingImg" src="someCoolUrl/img.png" onload="loadImage" height="300" width="300">
<button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="openedImage = null; openedImage = item.id; loadingImg = true;"></button>
```

Here is the component.ts

```
loadImage() {
    this.loadingImg = false;
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `load` event to your image tag, like so:

```
<img [src]="src" alt="Image not found..." (load)="loadImage()" />
```

This will call `loadImage` in your controller once it's loaded